# FlaskWTF validator prevents hiding form field

Tags: python, forms, flask

I am trying to build and submit a form using flask. My flask registration form function:

Form class:

```
class RegisterForm(Form):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired(), 
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email(), Length(min=6, max=40)])
```

jinja2 form:

```
<h1>Register</h1>
<br/>
<form id="registerForm" class="form form-register" method="POST" action="" role="form">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        {% for field in form %}
            {% if field.data==None %}
                {{ render_field(field) }}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
```

registration function:

```
@blueprint.route("/register/", defaults={'token': ''}, methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@blueprint.route("/register/<token>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register(token):
    email = confirm_token(token)
    form = RegisterForm(request.form, csrf_enabled=False, email=email)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
    .......
```

My plan is to only display fields I need filled out. In this case I already have the email so I don't want to show it, but sometimes I will need the email filled out. This works as expected with Get request, but on posting the results I get :

```
Email - This field is required.
```

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're better off removing the field conditionally on the server-side.

```
class MagazineIssueForm(Form):
    title  = StringField()
    year   = IntegerField('Year')
    month  = SelectField(choices=MONTHS)

def edit_issue():
    publication = get_something_from_db()
    form = MagazineIssueForm(...)

    if publication.frequency == 'annual':
        del form.month

    # render our form
```

See: http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/specific_problems.html#removing-fields-per-instance

Comment: Thank, I'll look into this.